# Is there any easy way to simulate my keyboard typing of a long text?

Tags: formatting, keyboard, whitespace, google-docs

I would like to copy paste a long plain text email into Google Documents. The email is indented with spaces, somewhat like this:

```
   Layer1
            Layer2
                    Layer3
```

When you paste this into Google Documents, it appears something like this

{tab} Layer1

{tab} Layer2

{tab} Layer3

The only way I can think of solving this problem is typing the whole email by hand, since then Google docs would respect my spaces as spaces (and not replace them with something that looks like a tab).

However, if I could give my plain text to a typewriter program, put the cursor inside my Google docs page and hit "Go", that would solve my problem.

Does anyone know of any such program, or of any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an AutoHotKey script:

```
 `::
 Send, [put in your text here]
 return
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bdares.

I downloaded the newest, UTF-8 Version of the program and replaced the default script with

```
#z::
(
SendRaw Level 1
    Level 2
        Level 3
)
return
```

The parentheses are necessary for multi-line text.

Reload the script, put the cursor into the text field (notepad or Google Docs, Notepad++ doesn't handle the line feeds correctly) and hit "Win-Z" (#z means Win-Z).

Important: If you are typing a long text with this script, be sure not to change the active window or your script will be interrupted. (Tested on Windows XP with Firefox 4 in Google Docs)